What metric spaces have the property that, if we go nearer to two endpoints, we also go nearer to inner points?
Let $(X,d)$ be a geodesic metric space (informally, a space that contains a "shortest path" between any two points). Let $A, C$ be two points in $X$, and let $B$ be any point on a geodesic between $A$ and $C$.
Suppose we stand on a point $Q$, and move to a point $P$ that is nearer than $Q$ to both endpoints $A$ and $C$. Intuitively, we would expect $P$ to also be closer to the inner point $B$. My question is: for what metric spaces is this true? In particular, for what metric spaces are the following assertions true?

$d(A,P) < d(A,Q)$ and $d(C,P) < d(C,Q)$ imply $d(B,P) < d(B,Q)$;
$d(A,P) < d(A,Q)$ and $d(C,P) \leq d(C,Q)$ imply $d(B,P) < d(B,Q)$;
$d(A,P) \le d(A,Q)$ and $d(C,P) \leq d(C,Q)$ imply $d(B,P) \le d(B,Q)$.

NOTE: the answer to this related question shows that 3 is true for the Euclidean metric, but not for the taxicab metric. I am interested in 1 and 2 too.

This is a very broad question. One can give sufficient conditions (e.g. $\text{CAT}(0)$). One can also give counterexamples. But the wording of your post make it sound like you expect some nice necessary and sufficient condition, and I don't think you'll get anything like that.

@LeeMosher Actually, I will be happy if there is a known term that describes these properties. It is somewhat related to quasiconcavity.

@LeeMosher a sufficient condition would also be very interesting. Why is CAT(0) sufficient?
